# Angular-UI-Bootstrap uib-tooltip doesn't hide when element lost focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tooltip, angular-ui-bootstrap

I use bootstrap uib-tooltip in a button it works fine but sometimes doesn't close tooltip.

Here

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-elevate btn-icon btn-icon-md mr-1"
        tooltip-placement="bottom" ng-click="onLoad()" uib-tooltip="{{ 'Refresh' | translate }}"
        ladda="isLoading">
        <i class="fa fa-sync"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: your syntax and usage is correct but certainly there must be an other error like css or some other thing. try to make a runnable code with https://codesandbox.io/ or some other tool in order to see your situation

Comment: @FarukT it happens when i use ladda,